# Set Margin in CSS on all Asp.Net controls

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible using css to set the margin on all asp controls like asp:RadioButton, asp:DropDownList, etc. the following obviously doesn't work but is there something like it that would?

```
    asp:Controls
    {
        margin: 5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could in fact do this:

```
input, textarea, table {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

and keep adding those you need.

Comment: That actually worked on some of it, not the dropdownlist's though

Comment: add select to the list input, textarea, table, select